# Why SpringBoot does not uses primitive data types instead it suggests to use Wrapper Class .?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am Working with Springboot and I declared int a; it suggested to create a bean with wrapper class.

Explanation of why we creating bean with wrapper class.

here is my code and error

````
package com.example.jwt;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JwtApplication {
    int a;
    int b;

    public JwtApplication(int a,int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public int area(){
        return a*b;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JwtApplication.class, args);
        JwtApplication ob = new JwtApplication(1,2);
        int area = ob.area();
        System.out.println(area);
    }

}

```Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.jwt.JwtApplication required a bean of type 'int' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'int' in your configuration.
````

Comment: When Spring creates an instance of `JwtApplication`, what values are you expecting it to use for `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with primitive vs. wrapper types.

When the line

```java
SpringApplication.run(JwtApplication.class, args);
```

is executed, Spring Boot will create an instance of JwtApplication for you, using it's dependency injection mechanism. Since the only constructor of JwtApplication has two int arguments, Spring Boot needs to know which numbers to use. And it has no way to know.

Solution: Don't do anything fancy in your main class. Remove all the extra code (and put it somewhere else), so that only

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class JwtApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JwtApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

remains.